# mac os high sierra: gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a ruby on rails app locally, and I am deep in a Command-line Pit of Doom and Despair. Any help is appreciated!

1. I ran `rails server`
   and got this error: `Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1`
2. I wrote `rvm install 2.5.1` and got this error: `-bash: rvm: command not found`
3. Visited the [RVM website](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) and followed their install instructions. I copied and pasted into the command line: `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`

This is where I get the error that I can't resolve:

```
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/Users/ocd11/.gnupg/S.dirmngr' failed: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

If I run `brew install dirmngr` it says it's already installed: `Warning: dirmngr 1.1.1_3 is already installed and up-to-date`

When trying to see what's in the path `ls  /Users/ocd11/.gnupg`, I get these three files: `S.dirmngr    crls.d      pubring.kbx`

Just to test it out I tried `cd /Users/ocd11/.gnupg/S.dirmngr` but I got the error `-bash: cd: /Users/ocd11/.gnupg/S.dirmngr: Not a directory`

I just want to run the rails server, but it seems so far at this point! 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Run dirgmnr in terminal directly.

In my case it shows me which library was broken, then brew reinstall them one by one till dirgmnr starts.